# Java: Howto know where the jar is located in Linux

Tags: java, linux, jar, working-directory

In Linux, the JVM sets the working direcory equal to the homefolder from the user.
In Windows is this the folder where the jar is located.
How can I find where the jar **(from my app)** is located to change the working dir?

Martijn

Comment: Which jar file are you asking about? Your application, the Java API or a third party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try obtaining the path to the jar with this code:

```
String path = YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
```

Then you can remove the "*.jar" part with:

```
path=path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

I had the same problem with a java game when I needed to open a file in the same directory the jar was.

Double clicking the jar in linux didn't open the file. Of course you can open a command line and change dir to the jar dir and then run the jar from there but I needed to double click the jar.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases it is the actual directory. Under windows automatically the actual directory is set to the base-dir of the jar, if you execute it from explorer. Under linux the home-directory is the actual directory for your GUI. To set the directory write a short shell-script, which sets the actual directory (with the cd-command) and then executes the jar (with javaw -jar xyz.jar).